# How can I show a spin in summernote?

Tags: jquery, summernote

I am trying show a spin, while a photo is upload with summernote, but summernote throw me a error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bookmark' of null.
The photo is save in my computer, but summernote doesn't show.

This is mi code:

```
 var awaitingPopUp = '<div class="text-right"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/spinner.gif" width="50px"/></><br /><br />';
          var edit = function() {
            $('.text').summernote({focus: true,height: 1000,
                 onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
                    sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
                    }
                });
          };

function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {
              var  processDialog=bootbox.dialog({ message: awaitingPopUp, title: 'Subiendo y guardando las fotos...' });
              var data = new FormData();
              data.append("file", file);             

              $.ajax({
                  data: data,                     
                  type: "POST",                   
                  url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addImageBlog.html/8",
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  success: function(url) {  
                      processDialog.modal('hide');
                      alert(url);
                      editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);


                  },
                  error: function(data){
                        alert("failure"+data);
                    }
              });
          }
```

Comment: I have just get resolve the issue, instead of use a bootbox or a normal modal, it is necessary the use of the class note-image-dialog modal. This class is inside of summernote-bs3.css.

Answer (score 0):

I have just get resolve the issue, instead of use a bootbox or a normal modal, it is necessary the use of the class note-image-dialog modal. This class is inside of summernote-bs3.css